# I am setting Flutter launcher icon using flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2 but when I run command it shows error NoConfigFoundException

Tags: flutter, icons, launcher, appicon

```
PS F:\Hitesh\Orhan\Flutter\Arfic\arificapp> flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in arificapp...                           4.7s
PS F:\Hitesh\Orhan\Flutter\Arfic\arificapp> flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
  ════════════════════════════════════════════
     FLUTTER LAUNCHER ICONS (v0.9.1)
  ════════════════════════════════════════════


✗ ERROR: NoConfigFoundException
Check that your config file `flutter_launcher_icons.yaml` has a `flutter_icons` section
```

Comment: Have you set a yaml file as specified in the point 1 of the Guide at [the pub page of the package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your own configuration before do that, look this example:

[Go example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOByQ.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors when answering a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Try to [edit] your answer and copy-paste it into the answer itself in between \`\`\` the_code \`\`\`.